# hydro xsens driver

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to install and run the MTi-G Xsens device is a IMU device.
Pls help and reply me thx.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157336/hydro-xsens-driver/) by [Rizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/13506/rizwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Try this - http://wiki.ros.org/xsens_driver

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Here you go -

I installed the fuerte release of the driver from the git -

1. Place the extracted folder in ros workspace
2. cd  ethzasl_xsens_driver-fuerte_released
3. rosmake xsens_driver
4. cd xsens_driver/nodes
5. ./mtdevice.py [commands] [opts]
   (read the Usage instructions on the ros wiki page of the driver for the arguments)

I hope this will help - Good Luck!

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1